# Pycharm keeps losing my Github password

Tags: github, pycharm

When I push changes to my github repo Pycharm asks for my github login info even though I've already entered it with the "Remember" checkbox checked

[image: Pycharm asks for login info]

Also, I've tried going into "File" -> "Settings" -> "Version Control" -> "Github" and set the password there but it doesn't help (and the password field is empty when I open the settings again)

I've been using Pycharm for over a year now and I've never had this problem before. It's not a problem with a new version of Pycharm either, because it has worked fine before on this version (Pycharm CE 2017.2.4)

Any ideas what have gone wrong and how I can fix this? Grateful for help!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there are some problems saving or reading passwords to the native keychain.

Try changing to Save in KeePass in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords

Comment: Thanks! (Upvoted but not accepted since i currently don't have the problem so i'm unable to verify)